# Upload CSV file to server using SFTP

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I think I am getting a bit lost.  I have a function that connects to a database and places the contents within a CSV file

```
private function obtainFile() {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".Config::DB_HOST.";dbname=".Config::DB_NAME."", Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from `some_table`");
    $stmt->execute();

    $filename = 'someFile.csv';

    $data = fopen($filename, 'w');

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($data, $row);
    }

    fclose($data);

    return $filename;
}
```

This is all good, when I execute it, I get the CSV with the data I expect.  The function returns the filename of the CSV file that was produced.

I then pass this CSV file location to another function so I can transfer it via SFTP

```
private function transferFile($csvFile) {
    $host = Config::SFTP_HOST;
    $port = Config::SFTP_PORT;
    $user = Config::SFTP_USER;
    $password = Config::SFTP_PASSWORD;

    $sftp = new SFTP($host, $port);

    if (!$sftp->login($user, $password)) {
        echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
    }else{
        echo $upload = $sftp->put($csvFile, $csvFile);
    }
}
```

So the file transfer without any issues, but the CSV file that is transferred is just a CSV file containing my file name!

Do I have to do something else to make sure I transfer the actual produced file, and not just a CSV file with the file name?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how the `put` method of your `SFTP` class is defined. What does each argument stand for? I assume the second argument represents the content  or payload to upload, and in your code snippet it's `$csvFile` which is presumable the CSV file path or file name

Comment: Appologies, using PHPSecLib http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put

Comment: `sftp->put('filename.remote', 'filename.local', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE)` creates filename.remote on the remote server such that the contents of it and filename.local match. ie. with NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE it uploads a file and without it it uploads a string.

Comment: So, did you like, read the documentation you just linked to? Seems you just need to add a 3rd `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE` argument

Comment: I did actually try that, and then my console displays Use of undefined constant NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE - assumed 'NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE'

Comment: Do `put('filename.remote', 'filename.local', 1)` instead, https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L71 I cant find that constant anywhere :/

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you using? The one on github seems to be more up-to-date at v2.0.9

Comment: @LawrenceCherone seems to be defined here in v1.0.9 (the version of SourceForge) ~ https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.9/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L99

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am using the 2.0 branch, and it looks like they have removed it but not updated the documentation.  I will try a 1 instead

Comment: Yup, you're reading the documentation for an older version. I apologise if some comments came off as harsh. Dealing with out-of-date documentation and resources is a pain. Stick to GitHub for both source code and doc references

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used 1 and it seems to work now.

Comment: @kate_hudson - the constant you need to be using is `SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE`